# Use C++ TensorFlow with WebAssembly backend

Tags: tensorflow, webassembly, tensorflow.js

For experimental purposes, is it possible to use a [C++ version](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc) of TensorFlow with the [WebAssembly backend](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/tree/master/tfjs-backend-wasm) from [tfjs](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs)?

If it's possible, then how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The WebAssembly back end you linked to  is the C++ version of TensorFlow, compiles to WebAssembly using Emscripten. It has usage instructions on GitHub.

Comment: There are instructions, but they are for JavaScript. Here I need to connect to the WASM backend from C++, so then I will be able to compile everything (backend + the code that creates and trains a model) in a single WASM module.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the wasm package for tfjs. Since the backend is asynchronous, you will wait until it is ready before you call your `main` function that will contain the tensors operation. The word of caution is that all operations are not yet supported by the wasm backend

```
// Import @tensorflow/tfjs or @tensorflow/tfjs-core
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
// Adds the WASM backend to the global backend registry.
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-wasm';
// Set the backend to WASM and wait for the module to be ready.
tf.setBackend('wasm').then(() => main());
```

Comment: Yes, but this is JavaScript. Is it possible to do the same, but in C++ ?

Comment: What have you tried in converting your c++ code to wasm ? If you have some errors in your attempt, it will be easier to help

Comment: For example, if I have a `TF_NewSession(graph, options, status);` call in C++, how can I use a WASM backend for a TF session?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible without as WebAssembly modules are imported and parsed by JS not C++. You won't be able to import a `.WASM` file into C++.

But the WASM backend that TensorflowJS uses is compiled to WebAssembly *from* C/C++ and Google provides [a repository, XNNPACK](https://github.com/google/XNNPACK) which allows you to access the low-level functionality directly if you really want to. You could build a project in C++ which imports XNNPACK functions and then compile it yourself to a single WebAssembly module.